# String replace with ListDictionary data is not woring

Tags: c#, html, replace

I was trying to replace tagged keys from html with values from ListDictionary. But it is not working how i expected. could anybody give me a solution.

My replacement method

```
    public static string GetDataAddedTemplate(string htmlTemplate, ListDictionary replacements)
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry item in replacements)
        {
            htmlTemplate.Replace(item.Key.ToString().ToLower(), item.Value.ToString());
        }
        return htmlTemplate;
    }
```

My html template is as folows

```
    <html>
<body>
        <table align="left" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 200px;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="text-align:center">
                            <th>Bill To</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="text-align:center">
                            <td>
                                <<username>>
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="text-align:center">
                            <th colspan="2">Payment information</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Date
                            </td>
                            <td><<createddate>></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Card holder</td>
                            <td><<cardname>></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Card</td>
                            <td><<cardbrand>> ############<<cardnumber>></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Amount paid</td>
                            <td>$<<amountpaid>></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>
        Congratulations! You've successfully purchased the <<shares>> plan.
    </p>
    <table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px;">
        <thead>
            <tr style="text-align:center">
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Plan</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr style="text-align:center">
                <td>1</td>
                <td><<shares>> Plan</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>$<<amountpaid>></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>
        <strong>Thank You</strong>!<br />
        Your business is appreciated
    </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Team</p>
</body>
</html>

And my ListDictionary is as follows

    ListDictionary replacements = new ListDictionary
                                       {
                                           { "<<UserName>>", "DisplayName" }, 
                                           { "<<CardName>>", "Name" }, 
                                           { "<<CardNumber>>", "Last4" }, 
                                           { "<<CardBrand>>", "Brand" }, 
                                           { "<<AmountPaid>>", "Amount" }, 
                                           { "<<CreatedDate>>", "chargeDetails" }, 
                                           { "<<Shares>>", "shares" }
                                       };
```

Comment: if its not working as expected, please add in the output and what you expect it to be

Comment: @chris, i gets output as same htmlTemplate string. No replacement happening with the code. Do you feel anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string` is immutable. So calling [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a new string and does not alter the existing string.

You need to use the returned string:

```
public static string GetDataAddedTemplate(string htmlTemplate, ListDictionary replacements)
{
    foreach (DictionaryEntry item in replacements)
    {
        // Use the string returned by Replace method
        htmlTemplate = htmlTemplate.Replace(item.Key.ToString().ToLower(), item.Value.ToString());
    }
    return htmlTemplate;
}
```

Comment: just to add a bit, as 'string' is immutable, it will create a new instance every time we perform 'replace' operation. When we are aware that we are going to make multiple replace operations, we should use StringBuilder. 

Modifying @Oliver's answer, it will look like.
StringBuilder htmTemplate = new StringBuilder(htmlTemplate);
foreach(...){ htmTemplate.Replace(...); }

return htmTemplate.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        foreach (DictionaryEntry item in replacements)
    {
        htmlTemplate = htmlTemplate.Replace(item.Key.ToString().ToLower(), item.Value.ToString());
    }
```